# .config autostart caffeine -a

Tags: linux, plasma5, autostart

I wish to run [**Caffeine -a**] at start of KDE.Plasma
I have run from the prompt **caffeine -h** which lists options for caffeine.
Options:
  -a --activate             Disables power management and screen saving.

In .config/atutostart I have created a  file with the following -:-

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Caffeine
Comment=Caffeine AutoStart
Exec=caffeine -a
TryExec=caffeine -a
StartupNotify=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Terminal=false
Hidden=false
```

This starts up Caffeine how ever the tac a is being ignored!?

Caffeine is started but NOT enabled.

How to autostart caffeine and enable autostart from .config/autostart?

Answer (score 0):

For the `-a` option, the latest version of caffeine I have only has two options: `-h` and `-V`. Unless you are not talking about the "inhibit autosuspend and screensaver" caffeine that I know of...

Perhaps you should report this to the package's [page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/caffeine) if you think there is a bug.